# I need to partition my drive for a dual boot

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

I am preparing for the Customer Preview for Windows 8 and I would like to have both Windows 7 and Windows 8 on my computer (dual booting).

However, I Don't want to lose my current data on Windows 7.  Is there a tool where I can create a new partition for Windows 8 (customer preview) but also keep my current Windows 7 install?

Free is best but if I have to do a paid app then I will.

Comment: There are lots of free tools.  Which ones have you tried?

Comment: none...  I'm looking for the best one (recommended).

Comment: If you have a HP or other Notebook, see this before trying to shrink or add any partitions, only applies if you have 4 pre-existing partitions from the manufacturer...http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-loaded-Windows-7/m-p/742019

Comment: My preferred method has always been to run GPartEd from a Linux live boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 has this ability built in. You can [shrink your current volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx) and then [create a new volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739429%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) in the unused space.

Answer (score 1):

An option to run both Windows 8 and Windows 7 is to [boot to VHD](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).  This will let you choose to boot into either Windows 8 or Windows 7 and you won't have to worry about partitions.

The performance hit for virtualizing the hard disk is minimal.  Everything else runs on bare metal.